# SAS How to extract a single string before a specific string?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to extract the number n before a string:

DEMO_DASHBOARD_n_START_TIME

How should I extract n?

I tried, but none worked:

```
  id = scan(name, -1, "_START_TIME");
  id = substr(name, index(name,"_START_TIME") - 1);
```

The number n has to be before _START_TIME, not just a digit in the string. Therefore compress() to extract just digits should not be used.

Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: can't reproduce your issue. Your first attempt works here.

Comment: It shouldn't - START_TIME would be the full delimiter.

Comment: So the first code sample works for the example line but not if there's any changes. Ie if the word was `n_START_TIME' it does not return correct results. It depends on how much variation you have in the data to some degree so if you can provide sample data that would be ideal. The SCAN() won't work because each element in the list is now a delimiter. If it's always at the end or the format is always the same, ie number of _ then it's easy. If it's more variable it's problematic.

Answer (score 2):

So, it's time for regular expression.

```
Pat = prxparse('/(\d+)_START_TIME/');
if prxmatch(Pat,) then ID = prxposn(Pat,1,Name);
```